# Connecting to a WIFI Network via Cocoa

Tags: cocoa, wifi

I'm building an app for my school which enables the pupil to connect to the school's wifi network (wpa2). Into this app the password has to be hard coded because the technician doesn't want it revealed.I've seen some examples such as XNetwork, but I'd rather use Cocoa than AppleScript.

Can someone suggest how this can be accomplished via Cocoa?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right way is not to make this an app at all, but to put the network password into a keychain which you put on the system image you apply to all of the machines. Then it will take considerably more effort to retrieve than a hard-coded password inside of an application, probably less effort to set up, and definitely less effort to enforce.

Make sure you put it into its own keychain. If you put it into the user's keychain, they'll be able to look it up using Keychain Access. If you put it into its own keychain, you can give that keychain a different password, and then students will be unable to examine the network password because they don't know the keychain password.